# PayPal Express Checkout Guest Option

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I'm trying to allow guest payment option in my express checkout integration.

I set up `SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole` and `LANDINGPAGE=Billing` in my `SetExpressCheckout` call, but it didn't work. I still get the create a PayPal account thing.

I heard that I also need to set PayPal Account Optional to ON in my PayPal account. The strange thing is that I couldn't find that option in my Business account! Any idea?

Comment: Post a sample of the request you're sending.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) (quote below), the SOLUTIONTYPE value will not work --

until you enable the "[PayPal Account Optional](http://eventespresso.com/forums/2010/07/account-optional-setting/)" setting. (see link for info & video)

> SOLUTIONTYPE
>   (Optional) Type of checkout flow. It is one of the following values:
>
> Sole – Buyer does not need to create a PayPal account to check out. This is referred to as PayPal Account Optional.
>
> Mark – Buyer must have a PayPal account to check out.
>
> **Note:** You can pass Mark to selectively override the PayPal Account
>   Optional setting if PayPal Account Optional is turned on in your
>   merchant account. Passing Sole has no effect if PayPal Account
>   Optional is turned off in your account.